Can't convert video with cuda after updating ffmpeg
i've used this command sometimes to convert 4k video into 1080p without problem with tool "ffmpeg batch" and ffmpeg 5.1? "2022-08-10-git-8fc7f0fdec-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 12.1.0 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project)" :

-map 0 -map -0:t -filter_complex "scale_cuda=1920:1080:format=yuv420p:interp_algo=lanczos,hwdownload" -fps_mode:v passthrough -c:v h264_nvenc -preset 18 -profile:v high -level 4.1 -b:v 13000K -rc cbr -c:a copy -c:s copy

this with pre-input "-hwaccell cuvid"
Now if i try to to the same with latest version of ffmpeg (6.1.1) it don't work. I've tried to change the pre-input with "-hwaccel cuda" but still nothing, it give me error "Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad scale_cuda:default".
If i try to add [v:0] before 'scale_cuda', i get this error (pgs subs error was present also before editing command):
[matroska,webm @ 0000025b18315680] Invalid Block Addition value 0x0 for unknown Block Addition Mapping type 68766345, name ""
[matroska,webm @ 0000025b18315680] Could not find codec parameters for stream 7 (Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
[matroska,webm @ 0000025b18315680] Could not find codec parameters for stream 8 (Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
Multiple -hwaccel options specified for stream 0, only the last option '-hwaccel cuda' will be used.
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'graph 0 input from stream 0:0' and the filter 'auto_scale_0'
[fc#0 @ 0000025b18311c80] Error reinitializing filters!
[fc#0 @ 0000025b18311c80] Task finished with error code: -40 (Function not implemented)
[fc#0 @ 0000025b18311c80] Terminating thread with return code -40 (Function not implemented)
[vost#0:0/h264_nvenc @ 0000025b183319c0] Could not open encoder before EOF
[vost#0:0/h264_nvenc @ 0000025b183319c0] Task finished with error code: -22 (Invalid argument)
[vost#0:0/h264_nvenc @ 0000025b183319c0] Terminating thread with return code -22 (Invalid argument)
[h264_nvenc @ 0000025b183692c0] 10 bit encode not supported
[h264_nvenc @ 0000025b183692c0] Provided device doesn't support required NVENC features
[vost#0:1/h264_nvenc @ 0000025b18330d80] Error while opening encoder - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height.
[vf#0:1 @ 0000025b18340900] Error sending frames to consumers: Function not implemented
[vf#0:1 @ 0000025b18340900] Task finished with error code: -40 (Function not implemented)
[vf#0:1 @ 0000025b18340900] Terminating thread with return code -40 (Function not implemented)
[vost#0:1/h264_nvenc @ 0000025b18330d80] Could not open encoder before EOF
[vost#0:1/h264_nvenc @ 0000025b18330d80] Task finished with error code: -22 (Invalid argument)
[vost#0:1/h264_nvenc @ 0000025b18330d80] Terminating thread with return code -22 (Invalid argument)
[out#0/matroska @ 0000025b18569c40] Nothing was written into output file, because at least one of its streams received no packets.
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lq=0.0 size=       0KiB time=N/A bitrate=N/A speed=N/A

of this if I try to use -vf instead of the "filter_complex":
[matroska,webm @ 000001814b872040] Invalid Block Addition value 0x0 for unknown Block Addition Mapping type 68766345, name ""
[matroska,webm @ 000001814b872040] Could not find codec parameters for stream 7 (Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
[matroska,webm @ 000001814b872040] Could not find codec parameters for stream 8 (Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle (pgssub)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
Multiple -hwaccel options specified for stream 0, only the last option '-hwaccel cuda' will be used.
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'graph 0 input from stream 0:0' and the filter 'auto_scale_0'
[vf#0:0 @ 000001814b895fc0] Error reinitializing filters!
[vf#0:0 @ 000001814b895fc0] Task finished with error code: -40 (Function not implemented)
[vf#0:0 @ 000001814b895fc0] Terminating thread with return code -40 (Function not implemented)
[vost#0:0/h264_nvenc @ 000001814b892780] Could not open encoder before EOF
[vost#0:0/h264_nvenc @ 000001814b892780] Task finished with error code: -22 (Invalid argument)
[vost#0:0/h264_nvenc @ 000001814b892780] Terminating thread with return code -22 (Invalid argument)
[out#0/matroska @ 000001814b88e240] Nothing was written into output file, because at least one of its streams received no packets.
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=       0KiB time=N/A bitrate=N/A speed=N/A  

Can someone tell me the correct way to do it now with an rtx 4090?

Add -report and rerun. Share report.

Reports are too big, i can't share them here. I did some other test and it work only if i add -vf "hwupload_cuda..." instead of the "-filter_complex" but is really really really slow, so this isn't the right way. Don't know why but it work perfectly with old ffmpeg as said above.

Check this report link and this link and this link.

"\\ffmpeg.exe" -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i "***.mkv" -y -map 0 -map -0:t -vf "scale_cuda=1920:1080:format=yuv420p:interp_algo=lanczos" -fps_mode:v passthrough -c:v h264_nvenc -preset 18 -profile:v high -level 4.1 -b:v 13000K -rc cbr -c:a copy -c:s copy -report "***.mkv" 

Nothing changed, this time i've used same video but without sound and subs:  link.

Apparently i've solved by using latest ffmpeg (v7) and this command:

-fps_mode:v passthrough -filter_complex "scale_cuda=1920:1080:format=yuv420p:interp_algo=lanczos,hwdownload"
-c:v h264_nvenc -preset 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v high -b:v 13000K -an -sn

With pre input:

-hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda

